# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Dokan>' of 'items'

Tags: flutter, dart

The data type in flutter is really bugging me out. i cant seem to get my head around this. Can anyone help me here?
I am using the Flappy search bar to print some data!

```
SearchBar<Dokan>(
          onSearch: search,
          onItemFound: (Dokan dokan, int index) {
            return Container(....)
          })
```

This is the search method that gets List

```
Future<List<Dokan>> search(String search) async {
    List<Dokan> dokans = await DokanApi.getAll('search', search);
    setState(() {
      this.isDescriptionPanelVisible = false;
      this.searchBarHeight = dokans.length > 0
          ? 70.00 + double.parse((dokans.length * 80).toString())
          : 120;
    });
    return dokans;
  }
```

This is the getAll method being called above

```
static Future<List<Dokan>> getAll([queryName, query]) async {
    ApiResponse apiResponse =
        await CallApi.get('dokans', queryName ?? null, query ?? null);
    if (apiResponse.hasErrors()) return null;
    return apiResponse.getData().map<Dokan>((dokanData) {
      return Dokan.fromJson(dokanData);
    }).toList();
  }
```

This is the Dokan fromjson method.

```
static Dokan fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Dokan(
      id: json['id'] ?? null,
      owner: json['owner'] != null ? json['owner']['name'] : null,
      location: json['location'] ?? null,
      name: json['name'],
      description: json['description'] ?? null,
      lat: double.parse(json['lat']),
      lng: double.parse(json['lng']),
      averageRating: json['averageRating'] != null
          ? double.parse(json['averageRating'].toString())
          : 0.0,
      totalRating: json['totalRating'] ?? 0,
      foodItems: json['food_items'] != null
          ? List<FoodItem>.from(json['food_items']
              .map<FoodItem>((food) => FoodItem.fromJson(food))
              .toList())
          : null,
    );
  }
```

Am i missing type casting something here? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show your `Dokan` class

Comment: Please provide actual stack trace for the error.

Comment: child: SearchBar<Dokan>(
              onError: (Error error) {
                print(error);
                return Text('');
              },
I am printing the errors from the widget itself. Its only showing that one line error. How can i print the tree?

Answer (score 0):

In getAll() what happens if you wrap your return with a typed list constructor? Like:

```
return List<Dokan>.from(apiResponse.getData().map<Dokan>((dokanData) {
      return Dokan.fromJson(dokanData);
    }).toList());
```

Comment: Doesnt make a difference

Comment: The error message you gave in your title is `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Dokan>' of 'items'` but I don't see a variable `items` anywhere in the code you've provided.  Like Mahori said, a stack trace would be useful.